# Eigenvalues of n matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

For $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, let $A_i=[a^i_{jk}]$ be a symmetric matrix. 
For $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, we assume that $a^i_{jj}=0$ for all $j$ and rank $(A_i)=2$. 
Then it has one positive and one negative eigenvalue.

In van Lint and Wilson "A course in combinatorics" page 79, they say that 
$A_1+\cdots+A_n$ can have at most $n$ positive (respectively negative) eigenvalues.

Could you tell me the proof?

Comment: Have you tried with Weyl's inequalities? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl's_inequality_in_matrix_theory ? That would be my first attempt.

Comment: Is there any restriction on the size of the matrices, e.g. should they also be $n \times n$?

Answer (score 4):

If there are more than $n$ positive eigenvalues, the linear span of eigenvectors for $n+1$ of them is a space of dimension $n+1$ on which $A_1 + \ldots A_n$ is positive definite.  There is then a nonzero vector $v$ in this space which, for each $i$,  is orthogonal to the eigenvector of $A_i$ for its positive eigenvalue.
But then $v^T A_i v \le 0$, resulting in $v^T (A_1 + \ldots + A_n) v \le 0$, contradiction.